# Stopping silent retries in HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` on *Android KitKat* to POST some data to a server. The server takes a long time to respond, and the connection is silently retrying 1 to 3 times before timing out. I don't want it to retry, since the server acts on all of the requests, resulting in Bad Things(TM).

I've tried `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false")` before opening the connection, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried [setReadTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int))? If server response takes long but doesn't send any package til then, it could probably work.

Comment: Already using setReadTimeout().

Comment: Are you sure your using the native `HttpURLConnection` and not a custom implementation like `okhttp` or `Volley`? AFAIK the stock implementation does not retry on SocketTimeoutExceptions.

Comment: The native HttpURLConnection is okhttp, which is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For POST calls set

```
httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

and this should fix the silent retries.
The bug report and workaround can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163595).

Comment: For a deeper understanding for the problem [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37675253/2061089).

Answer (score 0):

- Implement a hard timeout yourself, and force close the `HttpURLConnection` by [calling `disconnect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()). This can be done from your `Activity` using [`android handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html); If you use `AsyncTask`, you can simply call `cancel` or `Thread.interrupt()`:

  ```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          httpUrlConnTask.cancel(true);
      }
  }, timeout * 1000);
  ```

  And in your `httpUrlConnTask`, call `disconnect`:

  ```
  if (isCancelled()) {
      urlConnection.disconnect();
      return;
  }
  ```

  You may have to do `urlConnection` in another internal child thread so you can do a `while` loop in asynctask monitoring for `isCancelled`. And a `try..catch` so you can close all the streams properly.
- you already have `keepAlive` false, and `readTimeout`, consider adding [`connection timeout too`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)). This will set the socket timeout.

Comment: can you please post entire code im new to Handler, and suggest when to use Handler and AsyncTask

Comment: can confirm that calling urlConnection.disconnect(); solved atleast my issue of automated unwanted retries

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `System.setProperty("sun.net.http.retryPost", "false")`

Comment: I don't think this works with Android's HttpURLConnection implementation.

Answer (score -4):

[Android’s HTTP Clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Prior to Froyo, `HttpURLConnection` had some frustrating bugs. In particular, calling close() on a readable InputStream could [poison the connection pool](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2939). Work around this by disabling connection pooling:

```
private void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
    // HTTP connection reuse which was buggy pre-froyo
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read more information here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html